# Old Win 95 Game runs only at 640*480p. This is only a tiny fraction of my screen

Tags: windows, backwards-compatibility

I recently installed an old (1998) game from my childhood. It was designed for Win 95/98 but runs smoothly on Win10. However, its resolution is set to 640x480 and there is no way to change that (there is no settings menu, to begin with). On my 1440p screen this is only a very small rectangle in the middle of the screen and the better part of my screen is just black (see image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpyMM.jpg)

Is there a way to override the resolution a game is displayed in? Can this be upscaled somehow? I tried to google this but all the issues I found online are not applicable to me.

Comment: There are a lot of compatibility options. It would help if you could add which ones you have tried, and with which settings.

Comment: What is the game called ?

Comment: @AlanB it looks like "Mulle Meck bygger båtar"

Comment: Have you tried to lower your displays resolution or is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run old games on a screen that does not support lower resolutions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162395/how-do-i-run-old-games-on-a-screen-that-does-not-support-lower-resolutions)

Answer (score 1):

Check your GPU control panel settings. In the nVidia panel, for example, there is a section "Display > Adjust desktop size and position" with scaling options: "Perform scaling on GPU" & "maintain aspect ratio"